# How get widget size?

Tags: tkinter

Is there a way to precalculate widgets size before grid it?

Let say you have a frame filled with a button and label with text.

The text inside the label can differ in length, which will give you different frame size.

Comment: Try `.winfo_reqwidth()` and `.winfo_reqheight()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you that solved my problem. Do you know for what req is standing for?

Comment: @Module_art "requested"

Comment: Thank you make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed those methods winfo_reqwidth() and .winfo_reqheight() in the doc.

req in winfo_reqwidth stand for "requested" which do the job of precalculating size

I tried with .winfo_x() before, but got a return value of 1.